# Dynamic JMS Connections

Tags: spring, connection, apache-camel, integration

I need to know which framework or API to use for my following requirement. I am currently using native java code for all this.

**Requirement**
I have an application where there could be multiple JMS/Rest/TCP connections. These connections can grow at runtime. User wil have a screen to define new incoming or outgoing connections. I am using Native and works fine but I want to make use of an efficient framework or API like Spring, Camel etc ?

Need Guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to get this all working. There are multiple solutions to get do dynamic JMS
1. I used Spring JMS API and created the dynamic JMS connections by loading the dynamic child context into application. For this I followed the spring's dynamic FTP sample and inserted JMS beans in the example instead of FTP ones.
[Spring Dynamic FTP Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp)